# Adding text or string to the row of a matrix

Tags: matlab

I am having issues adding a label to the rows of a matrix. Here is the code I currently have:

```
Probability = ['Hole 1', US_par3_Win, par3_Draw, EU_par3_Win;
               'Hole 2', US_par3_Win, par3_Draw, EU_par3_Win]
```

I added the labels with single quotes, but am getting an error. Could anyone guide me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you pasted the error message into your question, along with the values of `US_par3_Win`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB matrices can only store elements of the same type. Cell arrays on the other hand don't have this restriction. I suggest you keep the matrix as it is, and add another cell array variable to store the label of each row. Example:

```
M = [1 2 3; 4 1 2; 4 1 1];
labels = {'row1'; 'row10'; 'row100'};

%# display 2nd row and its label
M(2,:)
labels{2}
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesnt seem to work for me. I get:

ans =

     4     1     2


ans =

row10


When running that code

Comment: That's exactly what I expect it to be!! Of course you can format the output a bit nicer with FPRINTF function for example.. Perhaps you should explain more what is it you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

If the variables, such as `US_par3_Win`, are scalars, the following should work:

```
Probability = {'Hole 1', US_par3_Win, par3_Draw, EU_par3_Win;...
               'Hole 2', US_par3_Win, par3_Draw, EU_par3_Win}
```

However, if the variables are e.g. 18-by-1 arrays, then you should combine them by creating first an array of Hole names

```
holeNames = arrayfun(@(x)sprintf('Hole %i',x),(1:18)','UniformOutput',false);  %'#
```

And then catenate like this

```
Probability = [holeNames,num2cell(US_par3_Win),...
               num2cell(par3_Draw),num2cell(EU_par3_Win)];
```

However, you're most likely much better off if instead of writing `'Hole 1'`, `'Hole 2'` etc, you just put the number of the hole in the first column of your `probability` array, i.e.

```
Probability = [1, US_par3_Win, par3_Draw, EU_par3_Win;...
               2, US_par3_Win, par3_Draw, EU_par3_Win]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to organize your data might be a [struct](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/struct.html). If you want to go even further use [classes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/briz6wl.html) to model your data.